# Reuse a partial with different content, in the same view

Tags: javascript, sails.js

As described in the Sails.js documentation:

> All of your locals will be sent to the partial automatically.

So I was wondering how I can use the same partial multiple times, in the same view, but with different content.

Let's say I have a list of the top 3 users, and a list of the newest 3 users.
The lists have the same HTML structure, and same CSS styling but their content is different.

How can I use the same partial (user/list.ejs for example) to display both the lists?
Does anyone know if there's a way to pass specific data to the partial, instead of the view locals?

Thanks in advance.

Dennis

Comment: You will need to [create template](http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html#create_template) to which you pass the data. [Image](http://www.embeddedjs.com/images/diagram.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sails uses the [ejs-locals](https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals) library to handle partials, which allows sending options to the partial as the second argument.  So in your template you can do:

```
<h1>Top users: </h1>
<p>
  <%= partial('user/list.ejs', {users: topUsers}) %>
</p>

<h1>New users: </h1>
<p>
  <%= partial('user/list.ejs', {users: newUsers}) %>
</p>
```

to supply different values for `users` inside in the `user/list.ejs` partial, provided that you supply `topUsers` and `newUsers` as locals when you display the view that's including the partial, i.e. in your controller action:

```
res.view("myView", {topUsers: [array of users], newUsers: [array of users]});
```